# How to scroll down with a nested scroll view in calabash-android?

Tags: android, scroll, android-nestedscrollview, calabash-android

So I am trying to scroll down an app with android but I get the following:

> Calabash::Android::WaitHelpers::WaitError: Could not find any scrollable views

but I have  a nested scroll with this "support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView" class. Does anybody know how can  I scroll down with calabash-android?

the scroll_down doesn't work for me.

Comment: this link will help you how to scroll with Nested Scroll view : 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKVk4d4FgBI

Comment: Thanks @Manidroid! I figured out that this ` scroll("android.widget.ListView",:down) `  helps !

Answer (score 1):

So the function below works fine but the scroll_down command won't work unless you have some ScrollView.

```
scroll("android.widget.ListView",:down)
```

or :

```
scroll("android.widget.ListView",:up)
```

also works fine with NestedScrollView:

```
scroll("android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView",:down)
```

and

```
scroll("android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView",:up)
```